# Using matplotlib to plot time on my x axis, however it starts from 0, not the actual start time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a CSV file with time data as follows:

`Time,Download,Upload
17:00,7.51,0.9
17:15,6.95,0.6
17:31,5.2,0.46`

I import the csv into a pandas dataframe: `df = pd.read_csv('speeds.csv', parse_dates=['Time'])`

And then plot the graph like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 7))
df.plot(ax=ax)
majorFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:')
minorFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:')
hour_locator = mdates.HourLocator()
min_locator = mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[15, 30, 45])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hour_locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFmt)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90, fontsize=10)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(min_locator)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(minorFmt)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=90, fontsize=8)
```

However the final graph starts from 00:00 like so, although the CSV file starts at 17:00:[image: Graph]

How comes the graph doesnt start at 17:00 also?

Another problem (while im here) is the major lables dont line up with the major markers, they are shifted left slightly how would I fix that?

Comment: What happens if you use `df.plot(ax=ax, x_compat=True)`? Does this change anything?

Comment: I get the same output unfortunately

Comment: Ok, can you make this reproducible somehow? It mightbe sufficient to also state the last couple of lines of the file.

Comment: Clearly you have data in your file for hours < 17:00

Comment: The `Time` column is not your index. Try `df = pd.read_csv('speeds.csv', parse_dates=['Time'], index_col=0)`

Comment: yeah there is data for hours 17:00 through 24 hours until the next 17:00, the thing is the graph is starting from 00:00 so all the data is shifted over. Full csv is here https://pastebin.com/ySRE5Thf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question - graph doesn't start at 17:00:**

Your csv only gives times (no dates) and it rolls over midnight. Pandas implicitely adds the current date to **all** times, so that times after midnight, which pertain to the next day, get the same date a times before midnight. Therefore you'll have to adjust the date part:

```
days = 0
df['Datetime']=df['Time']
for i in df.index:
   if i > 0 and df.at[i,'Time'] < df.at[i-1,'Time']:
      days += 1
   df.at[i,'Datetime'] = df.at[i,'Time'] + DateOffset(days=days)
```

and then use the Datetime column on your x axis.

**Second question - shifted major markers:**

Set horizontal alingment

```
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90, fontsize=10, horizontalalignment='center')
```

Comment: Even when setting the time column as my index, the time still starts at 00:00, however the shifted major markers is now fixed, thank you

Comment: @SamSims I changed the first part of my answer after you uploaded the csv file. Tested and works fine now.

Comment: Thank you, in the future I will ensure to save the date to the csv file as well